# MySQL 5.5 innodb performance - duration on CREATE TABLE AS ... query doesn't match to PROFILING table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to identify performance bottleneck on CREATE TABLE AS / INSERT INTO type of query. As per my previous investigation I'd found that source SELECT statement runs pretty smooth with response time under 1 sec. No issues on that side. The problem appears when I try to insert the result (approx. 9000 rows) into innodb table. This part takes more than 30 sec. - it doesn't meet expected SLA. 
   Right now I'm looking into INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING information in order to understand what is going wrong with my query. But output I'm getting is a bit confusing.

```
show profiles;
```

Returns the below result.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Query_ID |  Duration    |Query
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
'3'      |'0.03072700'  |'drop table `test_db`.`page_55`'
'4'      |'30.27254125' |'CREATE TABLE `test_db`.`page_55` AS SELECT ...'
'5'      |'0.00010050'  |'SHOW WARNINGS'
```

I can clearly see query ID = 4 which is my candidate with duration of 30 seconds. But when I investigate it further in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING then there is not any step that might cause such a long response. All entries are with Duration < 1 second as verified by below query

```
 SELECT sum(DURATION)
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING
 WHERE QUERY_ID = 4;
```

It returns 0.003308s which is completely different value than I've previously got from show profiles.

Does anyone has any idea how to interpret such a behavior?

Thank you very much.

Martin